# Find a document that has two numbers by a number

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How can I find a document which has two number field inside there (minNumber & maxNumber) by a number in mongoose?

For example, I have a document that minNumber is 80 and the maxNumber is 100 and my specific number is 78. This document should be returned because my specific number is between its minNumber and maxNumber.

I want to get a document that my specific number is between minNumber and maxNumber.

Can I write condition inside find method?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I write condition inside find method?

Yes, take a look at the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find).

What you're looking for should be:

```
YourModel.find({ minNumber: { $lte: specificNumber }, maxNumber: { $gte: specificNumber });
```